# Parsing xml response in Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse the xml  and get the value of the state.
Why is it not printing the state?

May be i am missing something in my code?
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>XML parsing cluster state </title>

<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
   // url: "cstate.xml",
      url: "jquery_xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) { parseXml(xml); }
  });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
  //find state and print the state

    //test 1
  $(xml).find("state").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
  });

//test 2    
  $(xml).find("cluster_info").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).find("state").text());
    $("#output").append(": " + $(this).find("state").text() + "<br />");
  });

}
</script>


</head>

<body>


<div id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cluster_info>
    <nodes>
        <entry>
            <key>Standby stuff</key>
            <value>
                <available_versions>
                    <available_version>62</available_version>
                </available_versions>
                <current_version>62</current_version>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </nodes>
    <target_state>
        <available_versions>
            <available_version>62</available_version>
        </available_versions>
        <current_version>62</current_version>
    </target_state>
    <new_versions>
        <new_version>38</new_version>
        <new_version>37</new_version>
    </new_versions>
    <removable_versions />
    <state>STABLE</state>
</cluster_info>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you get a response to your request? Does your sever receive the request? What happens?

Comment: Can you step into the success function and made sure the data is being returned into the xml variable? We want to make sure it's getting from the correct address and returning data and that your mime-types are setup.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the XML:

```
<state>STABLE</cluster>
```

should be

```
<state>STABLE</state>
```

Comment: Weird .. just tested it locally with your exact code and it printed the word STABLE (a total of 3 times to be exact :) ). Try checking your console for errors, maybe some path is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/NY6Gm/)

This work's just fine.

```
$(xml).find('state').each(function () {
    $('body').text($(this).text());
});
```